# Is it possible to put the mouse cursor behind an element or does the mouse cursor have an z-index?

Tags: jquery, css, mouse, z-index, mousemove

I would like to replace the mouse cursor with an custom image when the mouse hovers over a certain element. I do it by setting the mouse curser off first with

```
cursor: none;
```

when it hovers the element.

Then I read out the cursor position on the hovered element and set the css position of a graphic to the cursor position with a slight offset, so that the mouse curser is not over the graphic but still over the hover area.

I made a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/TimG/6XeWK/

Now it works quiet allright. The problem is just when you move the mouse very fast, the mouse cursor leaves the hover area and "slips" over the image what of course makes it impossible to determine the mouse position relative to the hover area (move very fast to the bottom left on the black hover area). I could make it a little harder to slip out of the hover area by setting the graphic to

```
display: none;
```

before the images' css position is changed and after it is changed setting it to

```
display: block;
```

again. Unfortunately it does not prevent this problem fully.

So: Is there any way of preventing this? Or is there a way to put the mouse cursor behind the hand? Kind of like setting a z-index to the mouse-cursor (my guess is, that it would not be possible, as it is no DOM element)?

Thx for any help.

Comment: You do know that `cursor:` in css accepts an url to an image ?

Comment: @adeno: +1 That should work what you saying. Hard to test in fiddler though. I tried that in fiddler and it would not work. Even with an image local to fiddler. I think in fiddler it is because it uses `fiddle.jshell.net` when rendering the output. But it should work as you said outside fiddler.

Comment: @adeneo: yes, I know that. Unfortunately I can't really use it, because the pointer graphic is visible before the mouse enters the hover area. So as soon as the mouse enters the hover area, that pointer graphic, allready there as a DOM element, becomes the mouse cursor.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - Spent quite a few minutes myself trying to make a fiddle with a custom cursor, but wihtout any luck. That's why I just posted it as a comment, cold'nt get it working, but I have done it on production sites before whith no issues what so ever ? As for the pointer graphic, why don't you just have an image with the pointer at the bottom, and on mouseenter just hide the image and use a custom cursor as well.

Comment: @adeno: that's a nice idea worth trying out... I would have to set the css of the image in the DOM to the last mouse position and show it again when leaving the hover area... 
I will update my question with the solution as soon as I tried it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Question

> is there a way to put the mouse cursor behind the hand?

The reason you see the mouse pointer when you move the mouse fast is that you occasionally end up with the cursor **over** the pointer, thus the `.hoverbox:hover` style is not applied.

In your `mousemove` event binding add the css style for `cursor: none` **also** to the pointer and you should not see the mouse pointer at all anymore even when accidentally moving over the hand. Applying the `cursor: none` to the `.pointer:hover` in CSS does not work as well.

```
$(".hoverBox").mousemove(function(e) {
    var tWidth = $(window).width();
    var position = $(this).position();
    var fingerPosition = position.top + e.clientY + 15;
    var fingerWidth = $(this).parent().find('.pointer').width();

    $('.pointer').css('display', 'none').css('top', fingerPosition).css('left', e.clientX - fingerWidth - 15).css('display', 'block').css('cursor', 'none');
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6XeWK/5/) - Hiding cursor when over pointer

**Edit**
I could not get the `cursor: url()` to work in fiddler but I'm guessing this is mainly down to the fact that fiddler renders output trough `fiddle.jshell.net` and the image might have to be local to the server.

But if all you want to use is a pointer-hand, you could always use the `cursor: pointer style` as well.

CSS:

```
.hoverBox {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6XeWK/7/) - Using the default pointer cursor

Comment: To hide the cursor when over the pointer is a nice idea but unfortunately the pointer graphic will still stop moving. As I mentioned in the comments of my questions I unfortunately can't use the custom mouse cursor via css because the pointer image is visible the whole time, even when the hover area does not get hovered. The pointer- style graphic in the fiddel is a bit misleading, in the project where I will use it, it is a picture of a realistic hand (and much bigger than in the fiddle), so I can't just use cursor:pointer...

Comment: @TimG: The pointer graphic only stops moving if you are not over the black box anymore, otherwise it should move fine regardless of the size of the image. What do mean exactly by it stops moving?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean – when the mouse cursor is over the pointer image, that image stops moving because the mouse has left the black box and entered the pointer graphic. And what I want is that the mouse is at no point able to enter the pointer image, no matter how fast the mouse movement is.