# Is it possible to give the cursor z-index?

Tags: javascript, css

I am guessing no, but it would be really sweet to be able to set the `z-index` of the cursor with CSS or Javascript.

Let's say you've got some buttons and you want to add a semi-transparent image on top of the buttons for effect. Or in my current case, some SVG paths that have hover and click actions. If I could set the button or SVG `z-index` to 0, my cursor's `z-index` to 1 and the image overlays `z-index` to 2, that would be pretty sweet! The mouse would be going under the overlay and still be able to click on the buttons. It would be even more spectacular to set the visual `z-index` (which layer the cursor appears to be), separate from the effective `z-index` (which layer the cursor actually is). So the cursor could appear to be on top of the overlay, but still be able to click on the buttons underneath.

I have my doubts, but I thought I would check if anyone has heard of someone doing this or something like it.

Comment: Spelling errors? SO has no spell checker. It is probably your browser's spell checker. You usually can right-click those words and add them to the dictionary.

Comment: z-index on cursors? Did you know about the "none" value? ie `cursor: none;`.

Comment: On topic, yeah `cursor:none` is most likely you're looking for, you'd just have to add `pointer-events:none` to the overlay as well, though the latter is not very cross-browser.

Comment: Not that I know of, but you could probably achieve the same effect by using a custom semi-transparent png as a cursor on the relevant areas. If you want to hide the cursor completely, you can use `cursor: none`.

Comment: This is about 7 years too late, but @FabrícioMatté - that worked perfect! +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since no answer has been accepted, I want offer the right answer.

The `pointer-events: none` is the solution.

See simple CSS example:

```
.emotion_message {
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: rgb(144,238,144,0.5);
    height: 20%;
    width: 94%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    color: darkgreen;
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left:3%;
    margin-right:3%;
}
```

In this example, I wanted to display a chart, with a static summary box over the top, but I wanted the cursor to interact with the chart underneath. I also added opacity to the `background-color`, so the user can both see and interact with the submerged element (in this case the chart). Now the user sees the box, but the cursor does not.

Thanks @FabricioMatte for this answer in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the cursor:none;

See a related Q: [Is it possible to put the mouse cursor behind an element or does the mouse cursor have an z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108897/is-it-possible-to-put-the-mouse-cursor-behind-an-element-or-does-the-mouse-curso)

Comment: +1 mate, that's actually pretty interesting what the guy was doing in his jsfiddles.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a cursor z-index.. what you can do is have a jQuery hover function that gets the object that the cursor is hovering over, which in return allows you to find the objects z-index. So really instead of wanting a cursor to have z-indexes, just have hover states.

Then have custom cursors depending on location. Which as everyone is saying `cursor:none` would be fun to play with for this. Say you want to go under a alpha block, you could just render a cursor under that alpha block to get the effect of the cursor being under it.