# I want to display div below cursor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to display div "box" below the cursor, what i have done is making div come on cursor i want to display it below the cursor

```js
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('.box').css({
    top: e.clientY - $(".box").height() / 2,
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

this prints the div just below cursor, I want it to appear below cursor.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you're expecting?

Comment: Does this answer your question.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12109131/16853979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add a margin to the top of your box.

**Example**

```
margin-top: 30px;
```

**With your code**

```js
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('.box').css({
    top: e.clientY - $(".box").height() / 2,
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: when i scroll down it doesn't follow any solution for that

Comment: If you want the div to follow the mouse while scrolling, you should add the `scroll event` similarly you did with the `mousemove event`.